# Issue with dynamic youtube player on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, safari

I've used a custom youtube player to play youtube videos directly on the website, inside a modal box.

Find the code below:

JS & HTML:

```js
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
            events: {
                onReady: initialize
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
```

```html
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="video-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="player.pauseVideo();">Pause</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its working fine on Chrome and Firefox, however on Safari the player is not even loading. Its just displaying the black screen. [image]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

**Add This Tag In Between head opening headClosing**

Comment: Its already added. Player div gets nothing but a black screen as attached above.

Comment: provide me your styles related with your video

Comment: There are no separate styles, used a material theme in the application. Its working fine on chrome and FF.

Comment: I am Asking About modal-content And Model Classes you need to customize These Classes

Comment: will be difficult to share, as I mentioned used material theme, and the modal box is nothing but using standard material styles. I'll try to edit the question with separate styles.

Comment: safari behavior Is Static That Both Classes Having Any Calculations Then It Will Not Able To Reflect At Safari ,You Need To Give Fixed Height And Width For safari only   Then Its Worked Fine